# Why does the order of arguments to hash_equals() matter?

Tags: php, timing-attack

The documentation for PHP’s [`hash_equals()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) (a string comparison function which is safe from timing attacks) says,

> It is important to provide the user-supplied string as the second parameter, rather than the first.

Why is this?

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911597/why-is-order-of-arguments-in-phps-hash-equals-function-important

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911597/why-is-order-of-arguments-in-phps-hash-equals-function-important) in duplicate question